# Coordinate where policeman catches thief if possible

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A policemen and a thief  are standing on x-axis with Policeman current position as (X1,0) and Thief is standing at (X2,0). Thief always runs away from Policeman . Policeman knows Thief is faster than him but this time Policeman is determined and chases Thief.

So for given coordinates of Policeman  and thief with their velocities V1 and V2 we need to **tell the coordinates at which Policeman catches Thief in integral time and if not possible then also tell that its "not possible".**

**Example** : If X1=4 and X2=20 and V1=10 AND V2=1 then here answer is (14,0)

**Explanation** :

At time t=0 coordinates of Policeman and Thief : (4,0) and (20,0)

Similarly, At time t=1: (14,0) (21,0) At time t=2: (24,0) (22,0)

thus answer is :(14,0)

**Example 2 :**

If X1=0 and X2=4 and V1=2 AND V2=2 then here answer is NOT POSSIBLE.

Comment: Are they stuck on the $x$-axis?

Comment: @Henry Yeah they are stuck on x-axis only

Answer (score 1):

If $|x_1-x_2|=0$ answer in Yes. If $|x_1-x_2|>0$ and $v_2<=v_1$ then  answer is No.The last case remains $|x_1-x_2|>0$ and $v_2>v_1$. 
For this case suppose the thief has run distance $d$ when he is caught, so police has moved $d+|x_1-x_2|$.They have attained this in say time $t$ we get
$$v_1t=d$$
$$v_2t=d+|x_1-x_2|$$
we get by both
$$v_2t=v_1t+|x_1-x_2|$$
$$t=\frac{|x_1-x_2|}{v_2-v_1}$$
so if $|x_1-x_2|$ is divisible by $v_2-v_1$ then answer is Yes,otherwise No.
Yes means thief is caught.
Say if thief gets caught the we know $t$, so we know $d$ from first equation.If $x_1<=x_2$ then co-ordinate is $(x_1-d,0)$ otherwise $(x_1+d,0)$.

Comment: What about coordinate if theif is caught?

Comment: if possible get value of t and from equations get the co-ordinates

Comment: You miss the case when both speeds are equal

Comment: No i did not please read carefully

Comment: i think it should be if v1<=v2 then answer is NO..am i right ?

Comment: In my case v1=velocity of thief and v2= of police same for x1,x2 sorry about that

Comment: for thief coordinate at (20,0) and velocity as 1 and police at (4,0) and velocity as 10 your answer is NO.But answer is (14,0)

Comment: How can it be (14,0) as thief runs away from police if if he gets caught his x co-ordinate should have been greater than 20

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1, x_2, v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.
You need to find when $\exists \; t \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $t \geq 0$ such that:

$
\begin{align*}
& (x_1 + v_1 t) = (x_2 + v_2 t) \\
\Leftrightarrow \qquad & (v_1 - v_2)t = x_2 - x_1
\end{align*}$

This gives 2 cases. **Case 1**: If $(v_1 - v_2)=0$, then for $t$ to exist we must have that $x_1 = x_2$. In which case the equation is satisfied $\forall t \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $x_1 \neq x_2$, then $\not \exists t$.

**Case 2**: If $(v_1 - v_2) \neq 0$, then $t = \frac{x_2 - x_1}{v_1 - v_2}$. Then what we need to happen for $t$ to be an integer is clear: $(v_1 - v_2) \mid (x_2 - x_1)$. We also need $t \geq 0$. Since you said that the thief is faster than the policeman $v_1 \leq v_2$.
So for $t \geq 0$ we must have that $x_1 \geq x_2$.

To get the coordinates just plug in the value of $t$. The policeman will be at $(x_1 + v_1 t)$, the thief at $(x_2 + v_2 t)$.